# Word/Phrase to Describe Colin Kaepernick Pile-On

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, social-interaction

I imagine the word I am looking for to be related to Social Sciences.  I am looking for the word describing brownie points that one receives from her peers for expressing outrage at a socially frowned upon act or fact.

The word should express that the person casting aspersions does so without thought, experience, or consideration for the subject they rebuke.  This word would identify the fuel for mob mentality and behavior.

Example Sentence:

Jane is simply ___________ in her repudiation Colin Kaepernick.

Comment: It ought to be called the "[Nicolas Chauvin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Chauvin) Award for Exemplary Citizenship." Or perhaps we could call such a person—in the tradition of "armchair quarterback" —a "bonespur patriot."

Comment: Wow, _chauvinism_ is actually close to what I am looking for but it's specific to patriotism.  I am looking for something that could be applicable to the turd situation as well - a more generic form of the chauvinism concept.  Thanks!

Comment: Pandering might be closer to what I am looking for; or Political Expedience.

Comment: What type of word are you looking for? Please add an example sentence.

Comment: "piling on", how you described it, would work.

Comment: Some friendly advice: your question has been all over the map. You should try to avoid that in the future. :-) It results in a lot of wasted time and effort by ELU users.

Answer (score 1):

One could say

> adulation,

but maybe that's not capturing the essence you're asking for. Judging by the question, it seems like you want the word to capture a *sneering* aspect.

I guess you could say they were all

> Righteously Indignant.

Or in a word

> self-righteous

I saw this answer on this site a while back:

> they were all members of the [Mutual Admiration Society](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mutual_admiration_society)

Answer (score 1):

Filling in the blank in the OP's example:

> Jane is simply engaging in **reprehensible "group think"** in her
>   repudiation of Colin Kaepernick.

[**group think**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/group%20think): a pattern of thought characterized by self-deception, forced manufacture of consent, and conformity to group values and ethics

[From Merriam-Webster]

Comment: group think seems to be it.  There must be a more sophisticated sounding term or word for it though...  Thanks Richard.

Comment: @RonRoyston Maybe the phrase you're looking for is mob mentality or piling on.

Answer (score 0):

Word describing brownie points that one receives from her peers for expressing outrage at a socially frowned upon act: **affirmation**

> [**affirmation**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affirmation):
> something affirmed
>
> [**affirm**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affirmed): to
> assert (as a judgment or decree) as valid or confirmed
>
> [Both Merriam-Webster]

And the OP's example:

> If I were the first person to communicate the unpleasant odor
> associated with a stinky turd hidden in a room full of people in a
> professional setting, I would win brownie points, i.e., the
> **affirmation** of the group, for both being "courageous" enough to voice my displeasure and for experiencing the displeasure along with
> the group.

Addendum: **Affirmation** focuses on what the speaker receives from the other members of the group in positive terms: the brownie points constitute **affirmation**. If the OP is instead trying to characterize the behavior of the speaker and the group in negative terms, as judged by an independent third party with opposed values, I would consider words such as the following:

> [**reprehensible**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reprehensible):
> very bad : deserving very strong criticism
>
> [**disgusting**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disgusting): so bad, unfair, inappropriate, etc., that you feel annoyed and angry
>
> [**objectionable**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objectionable):
> not good or right : causing people to be offended
>
> **condemnable**: worthy of a statement or expression of very strong and definite criticism or disapproval
>
> All Merriam-Webster]

And so, for example, the behavior of the speaker and group providing affirmation in the form of brownie points is **reprehensible**.

Comment: Not bad, I just edited my senario.  However, I'm looking for a word that captures the corruption of, as you put it, affirmation.  Actually corrupt just might be the word I'm looking for.  Thanks Richard.

Comment: @RonRoyston Hey. You should state your question more precisely, more along the lines of your comment. "Corruption" refers to a value judgment of the brownie points received by your subject, whereas your question focused on the characterization of the underlying essence of those brownie points. I've tried to addressed the latter.  What exactly are you looking for? I might give it another try based on this exchange. Thanks.

Comment: @RonRoyston I added an addendum to my answer. I hope it comes closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

#### [corrupt](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/corrupt)

> *adjective*
>
> 1. having or showing a willingness to act dishonestly in return for money or personal gain.
>
> (Oxford Dictionaries)

Comment: This appears to be a quotation. Please follow the [network rules](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and show it as a quote, with a citation and preferably also a link if it's available online.

Answer (score 0):

**A tool.**

> Someone who is easily manipulated by others, because they substitute the judgment and/or approval of others for their own. The others can be admired friends, strangers or potential mates whose approval the tool seeks. Especially in interpersonal situations, the tool will seek approval from the other, but fail to exercise their own judgment about whether the other person is good or right for them. Alternately, the tool will allow public figures, advertising, or other mass media to replace or form their own opinions on any number of subjects -- most evident in fashion and music choices (often fads or heavily marketed products of suspect quality or style). **Somewhat less obvious are tools whose opinions on current events are parroted from sources thought by the tool to be reliably correct -- if you don't follow current events, or didn't come across the original source, you might not realize they hadn't actually given their opinion much thought beyond memorizing the highlights.** The recurring theme is that the tool avoids using their own judgment, sometimes even failing to acquire an ersatz opinion; instead just seeking approval. The tool is an open field for anyone who would like to use them for their own purposes. When they choose very poorly, it is obvious to most that the tool has been manipulated and was foolish to have allowed it. Usually singular in actual usage, but sometimes phrases like 'tool shed' or 'hardware store' are used to refer to groups seen as clearly lacking common sense.

Bold mine.
From Urban Dictionary
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tool&defid=1687477

The point being that the tool is arbitrarily selected and exploited and receives no compensation from the group that benefits from the tool's action.

Answer (score 0):

"Piling on" or piling it on is probably a very good fit (as Mitch suggested in the comments).  It suggests that your person isn't reacting out of personal offense or outrage, but just because everyone else is doing so.

so, "Jane hasn't really thought about her repudiation of Kaepernick, she's just piling on because everyone else was talking about it"

The phrase [seems to originate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/piling+on) from football, where a player might be jumping on a pile of people simply because there must be a reason they're piled up like that (not because they can, yanno, actually see the cause).  It has also gained the meaning "To add or increase (something, such as criticism) abundantly or excessively" - which does seem to fit the usage you're looking for.